# Getting cannot convert object to ArrayList error when retrieving ArrayList from HttpSession

Tags: java, servlets, casting, httpsession

I have saved an ArrayList to the session object. I am trying to retrieve it using

```
sriList = session.getAttribute("scannedMatches");
```

I am getting the compile time error "Cannot convert from Object to ArrayList". How can I get my ArrayList back from the session object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`HttpSession#getAttribute()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method returns `java.lang.Object`:

```
public java.lang.Object getAttribute(java.lang.String name)
```

Did you try to cast the returned object?

```
sriList = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("scannedMatches");
```

Comment: +1 `The HttpSession#getAttribute() method returns java.lang.Object:`

Comment: Thanks - normally my IDE recommends a cast when it makes sense, so I thought there must be someting different here.

Comment: Is this a sign we are becoming to IDE dependant?  I remember programming my first apps in notepad with command line javac... my first BIG program I did without autocomplete...

Comment: in notepad!! what are you saying Zoid.

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast it.

```
sriList = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("scannedMatches");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Object scannedMatchesObj = session.getAttribute("scannedMatches");
if ( scannedmatchesObj instanceOf List ){
    sriList = (ArrayList)scannedMatchesObj;
    //Do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: Just becuase (scannedmatchesObj instanceof List) is true, doesn't necessarily mean it's an ArrayList.  Might be a better idea here, depending on the circumstances, to declare sriList as a List, and cast accordingly.